# How to store different data from JSON to different fields in django/python

Tags: python, django

I'm sending a request with POSTMAN to my server, and getting JSON with such function

`__get_json__` it work well.
Here it is by the way.

```
def __get_json__(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
            json_data = json.loads(data)
            json_response("OK")
            return json_data
        else:
            return error_response(406, "Request was not a json or POST type")
    except ValueError:
        return exception_error(500, "Server Issue")
```

and after here i'm returning in the function `register_user`

```
def register_user(request):
    user_jsonify_data = __get_json__(request)
```

I wanna to store my data to different fields, for example i have such JSON

```
{
    "name": "Tenders",
    "id": "2135324123",
    "set": "set"
}
```

How can i split it correctly?

Comment: Unrelated, but don't create your own double-underscore method names. Just call it `get_json()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay, thank you, i will know

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're using POST and assuming you're posting form data, then why don't you use a Django [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/) to process the data (and more importantly **validate** it) and then store it? You shouldn't first parse it as json.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm new in django, it is my first project. As far as i understood, i'm getting from frontend json file, that's the reason why i dont use Django Form, or perhaps i just miss understood my colleges.

Comment: This is exactly what [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), and its ModelSerializers, are for.

Comment: Ok, if you're writing an API that accepts json as input, then you need a serializer to deserialise your json data to valid python objects/django models. This is what the Django REST framework was written for, as Daniel just mentioned.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you both guys, i will search more about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. pip install djangorestframework
2. add `rest_framework` to settings.INSTALLED_APPS
3. Example:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    set = models.CharField(max_length=30)

# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer
class RegisterView(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```